# Ввод в postresql через переменную. Python

Tags: python, postgresql, переменные, ввод

В sqlite3 я могу сделать так:

```
user_id='?'
grade ='?'
mas=(user_id,grade)
cursor.execute( "INSERT or IGNORE INTO users(userid, grade) VALUES(?, ?)" , mas)
base.commit()
```

Как сделать нечто подобное в postgresql?
Я разобрался как создать таблицу и законнектиться к БД на сервере, но понятия не имею как запихнуть в БД переменные из массива. Желательно не через mas[0] и mas[1], но скажите хоть-как нибудь как сделать.

Comment: http://zetcode.com/python/psycopg2/

Comment: Если ваше средство работы с БД принимает параметры как отдельные свои параметры, то просто распакуйте массив при передаче, как `*mas`

Comment: Всё норм, уже сделал.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users(userid, grade) VALUES {mas}" )
```

Comment: Это создаёт уязвимость под названием sql-инъекция, так делать нельзя.

Comment: @andreymal как правильно?

Comment: @Jack_oS в документации psycopg2 есть пример использования параметров, почти ничем не отличается от sqlite3 https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Спасибо. Так лучше, безопаснее, да печатать мне при переносе кода с sqlite на postgres меньше. Запиши как ответ.